# Multiple instances using select2

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-select2

I've been trying to develop a interface for a system where the user is supposed to add some items with their respective quantity, serial numbers and observations as well.

So, I´m gonna show a table with one single row, but clicking on a button to add row, another row is added in the bottom.

I used Select2 in a column so that the user can add more than a serial number in the same input and its working as a charm. However, when I click the button add row, another row is add, but the plugin is not started. I think it may be something simple, but I'm not really used do jQuery.

Hope you understand my question, guys.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--adição e exclusão das linhas da tabela-->
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    function Adicionar(){   
        $('#tab_logic tbody').append("<tr id='addr"+(i+1)+"'><td><select class='selectPretty form-control' placeholder='Descrição' name='material"+i+"' required><option></option><option value='Rádio VHF PRO 5150 Motorola'>Rádio VHF PRO 5150 Motorola</option><option value='Rádio VHF PRO 5100 Motorola'>Rádio VHF PRO 5100 Motorola</option><option value='Mesa de Som 4 canais Maxtor'>Mesa de Som 4 canais Maxtor</option><option value='Microfone sem fio Cantabem'>Microfone sem fio Cantabem</option></select></td><td><input  name='qtde"+i+"' type='number' placeholder='Qtde'  class='form-control'></td><td><select class='selectPretty form-control' name='serial"+i+"' multiple='multiple' placeholder='Serial'><option value='3859'>3859</option><option value='4568'>4568</option><option value='7741'>7741</option><option value='1259'>1259</option><option value='9965'>9965</option></select></td><td><input  name='obs"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Observações'  class='form-control'></td> <td><button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger btnExcluir'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></button></td></tr>");
        i++;
        $(".btnExcluir").bind("click", Excluir);
        $(".selectPretty").select2();
    };
        $("#addItem").bind("click", Adicionar);
    function Excluir(){
        var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
        par.remove();
    };
    function Select(){
        $(".selectPretty").select2();
    };
    $(".btnExcluir").bind("click", Excluir);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Install Firebug or something to see the console and check if there is an error when you add a new row.

Comment: Can you show us an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Buddies, I couldnt get to upload my example on jsFiddle, however I uploaded it to my server on the internet, you can check it clicking on the link bellow:

[http://.f59.com.br/ccom/criar-cautela.php](http://www.f59.com.br/ccom/criar-cautela.php)

Answer (score 2):

I hvae update some code in the jsbin

```
  $("#tab_logic").find("tbody tr").find("td:eq(0)").each(function(index,val){
          var name = $($(this).html()).prop('name');
        $(':input[name='+name+']').select2();
      });   

  $("#tab_logic").find("tbody tr").find("td:eq(2)").each(function(index,val){
          var name = $($(this).html()).prop('name');
        $(':input[name='+name+']').select2();
  });
```

JSBIN 
http://jsbin.com/wicutoti/17/edit

Comment: Dear @holmes2136, I´d like to thank you for your help. It was very usefull for me and it worked like a charm.
It took me some time to make it work, but its because I was trying to mix my code and  yours, when I used only yours, it worked and then I added some of my codes.
I´m sorry for the delay in the answer, but I was busy working on another project. 
Thanks to everyone who tried to helpe me as well.